# Samsung Smart TV SDK - Web Socket

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I have created a simple application to create a Web Socket for my Smart TV Emulator. This is my web socket code -

```
if ("WebSocket" in window)
{
    alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9998/echo");

    ws.onopen = function()
    {
        console.log("Socket open.");
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
    { 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        console.log("Message is received...");
    };

    ws.onclose = function()
    {
        console.log("Connection is closed..."); 
    };
}

else
{
    console.log("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
}
```

The console log shows the message `Web Socket is supported by your Browser!!` but further on the log prints `Could not connect to localhost:Connection refused.` How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Is there something actually listening on port 9998 to accept the connection?

Comment: Yes. I have a python script listening on that port.

Comment: What SDK are you using? What emulator? Is it 2012-2013 version or VirtualBox one?

Answer (score 1):

This answer can help you to continue further: [Using WebSockets on Samsung Smart TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162616/using-websockets-on-samsung-smart-tv)

Basically problem source can be on version of the Samsung Smart TV, firewall, port (emulators can have separate IP too) and application you are trying to connect through the web socket. Utilize Samsung Log since they help a lot in problem solving. The code itself doesn't give much information to locate the source of the problem.

Hope this helps you forward (:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to connect to localhost:9998 from your SmartTV. This might work from your browser, but not when you try to run it from emulator or SmartTV. It is better to use the IP of your PC.